# Proving a function is differentiable at a point if and only if a certain limit holds

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Prove that a function $f$ is differentiable at $x = a$ with $f'(a) = b$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x) - f(a) - b(x-a)}{x-a} = 0.
\end{align*}

This is a question in an elementary analysis course. My (very brief) proof is as follows :

$f'(a) = b \in \mathbb{R}$ $\iff$ $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = b$ $\iff$ $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{b(x-a)}{x-a}$ $\iff$ $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x) - f(a) - b(x-a)}{x-a} = 0$.

Since the proof is so short and I've only seemed to use a bit of calculus, I can't help but think there is a subtle detail that I'm brushing over, and the proof is incorrect. Is the above proof correct, or have I missed something ?

Thanks !

Comment: Rest assured, it is correct.